# Not fully transparent background on urxvt

Tags: rxvt

I looked up several answers on StackExchange network, neither of them worked as I wanted.

I started using `urxvt` on Ubuntu instead of `gnome-terminal`, and wanted to configure it's look to be similar. I succeed with fonts, but can't beat transparent background. What I want is mix **60% background and 40% Ubuntu Mid aubergine (`#5E2750`)** -- that's how my `gnome-terminal` was configured. I tried several combinations of values for `Urxvt*background` (tried with alpha channel too), `Urxvt*transparent`, `Urxvt*backgroundPixmap`, `Urxvt*fadeColor`, `Urxvt*fading` (doesn't look actually useful here, but most examples I met set that too) and `Urxvt*shading` in `.Xresources`. Every one was not even close, most of them gave completely black background. Looks like I am wrong at understanding `backgroundPixmap` and `background` settings, but documentation is not so rich about them.

Answer (score 0):

Referring to 9.20 (since it seems this area is currently under development, post-9.22 early this year, e.g., [see github mirror](https://github.com/exg/rxvt-unicode/tree/master/src)).

`urxvt` applies the background pixmap after doing the other background transparency operations (it doesn't really combine them).  To see this, look at the `rxvt_term::bg_init ()` method in background.C:

```
void
rxvt_term::bg_init ()
{
#if BG_IMAGE_FROM_ROOT
  if (option (Opt_transparent))
    { 
      if (rs [Rs_blurradius])
        root_effects.set_blur (rs [Rs_blurradius]);

      if (ISSET_PIXCOLOR (Color_tint))
        root_effects.set_tint (pix_colors_focused [Color_tint]);

      if (rs [Rs_shade])
        root_effects.set_shade (rs [Rs_shade]);

      rxvt_img::new_from_root (this)->replace (root_img);
      XSelectInput (dpy, display->root, PropertyChangeMask);
      rootwin_ev.start (display, display->root);
    }
#endif

#if BG_IMAGE_FROM_FILE
  if (rs[Rs_backgroundPixmap])
    { 
      fimage.set_file_geometry (this, rs[Rs_backgroundPixmap]);
      if (!bg_window_position_sensitive ())
        update_background ();
    }
#endif
}
```